# How to dequeue css file belonging to a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Hi there How to dequeue css belonging to the plugin with wp_dequeue_style in a child theme?  The path of the file is this:
plugins/td-standard-pack/Newspaper/assets/css/td_standard_pack_main.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dequeue a file, you first need to find the ID of that particular css/js file by checking the View Source of the page.

Once you locate the ID, then you can just dequeue the css/js file using the code code.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rf_remove_resources', 999 ); 
function rf_remove_resources() {
 
    wp_dequeue_style('td-standard-pack-framework-front-style-css'); 
    wp_dequeue_style('td-standard-pack-framework-front-style'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found css id from the page source and I put it instead of cff but I see the file in lighthouse in coverage. it doesn't work as I said CSS file belongs a plugin.                                    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rf_remove_resources', 999 );
function rf_remove_resources() {    
    wp_dequeue_style('td-standard-pack-framework-front-style-css'); // stylesheet id

Comment: I have updated my answer. You have to remove the "-css" from the ID. Do accept the answer and upvote it if this helps

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I copied your code in the function, but the file was not dequeued and I see it in the coverage.@Rajeev

Comment: That might be due to the cache as well.  Do clear the cache and check the Page Source and see if the CSS file is still loading.

Comment: I try remove unused css for the first time on a subdomain where there is no cash. I used codes on Wordpress. org but it didn't work too.  <pre><code>  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mywptheme_register_styles' );
function mywptheme_register_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'mywptheme', get_stylesheet_uri() );

} 'code' add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mywptheme_child_deregister_styles', 11 );
function mywptheme_child_deregister_styles() {
 wp_dequeue_style( 'mywptheme' );

} <code> @Rajeev

Comment: Join this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/247833/wp-dequeue-support?tab=access
or Try this plugin to see if this does the job for you.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-asset-clean-up/